# I am using $_POST without filtering and PDO for inputting data on MYSQL DB, Is my code still vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo

Here is something that I am doing,
- code -

```
 $insert_content = "INSERT INTO POSTS(content) VALUES ( ? )";

 $stmtinsert = $pdoinsert2->prepare($insert_content);
 $stmtinsert->bindParam(1,$content);
 $inserthere = $stmtinsert->execute();

 if($inserthere){
 echo "Your content has been posted!";
 }
 ?>
```

I was previously doing,
     $content = htmlentities($_POST['c']);
but it did not store foreign languages like Korean, Chinese, Nepali in proper form. In order to show the foreign languages, I had to switch to No Filtering.

Is there any way to input foreign languages other than I have done along with proper sanitizing? Or If there is not, Is what I am doing safe from security point of view?

Comment: It always safe to presume the user is a cracker and clean every thing prior to adding it to your database even using a prepared statements it's best to clean user inputs.

Comment: @sand define "clean"

Comment: Assuming that you're not emulating prepares, yes - this is perfectly fine.

Comment: SQL injection is not the only vulnerability exists in the world. And you can guess that a function called **html entities** hardly have any relation to **SQL**. So, regarding sql your code is good but to protect from XSS you should use htmplspecialchars, setting the appropriate encoding as a parameter.